# Information of each iteration in while loop inside a method

Tags: python, class, loops

I have a method from a class where I have a `while` loop and I would like to return something at each iteration.

```
class Machine():
    def __init__(self):
        self.ActReturn = 0

    def ExecuteM(self, Var1, Var2):
        while Var1 != 'stop':
             Var2 = Var2 + 3
             self.ActReturn = self.ActReturn + 1
             sleep(0.5)
```

then I would like to call `ExecuteM` but to get "something" for any execution of the `while` loop and be able to modify a graphic interface.

```
def main(self):
    temp = 0
    self.TM.ExecuteM(var1, var2)
    if self.TM.ActReturn > temp:
        self.result.setText(Result())
        temp = temp + 1
```

But for sure it doesn't work this way, because `ExecuteM` will be executed until the end of his `while` loop and then the text will be set....
how could I create this communication?

**EDIT**

If I try something like :

```
class Machine():
    def __init__(self, result):
        self.result=result

    def ExecuteM(self, Var1, Var2):
        while Var1 != 'stop':
             Var2 = Var2 + 3
             self.result.setText(Result())
             sleep(0.5)
```

Why it does not work ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly: you want to use a `while` loop to change some values and have those values change the state of a GUI. Why place the while loop within a separate function then?

I think you would be better off if you had a `while` loop in your `main` function that called `setText` and (the necessary logic within) `ExecuteM` during every iteration.

Just move the functionality so you are not calling `setText` once per loop; instead call it once per iteration.

Comment: I was thinking doing this but I would like to separate the graphic part from the "machine" script which process information.... but I don't even know in this case if it's possible....

Comment: It is possible to separate the (non-looping) functionality into a class based ExecuteM method, but what isn't possible is calling setText within main() more than once per ExecuteM execution.